# Pyspark fill null value of a column based on value of another column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: col1 and col2:

```
col1 col2
aaa  111
     222
ccc  333
```

I want to fill the null values (here the 2nd row of col1).
Here for example the logic I want to use is: if col2 is 222 and col1 is null, use the arbitrary string "zzz". For each possibility in col2, I have an arbitrary string I want to fill col1 if it's null (if it's not, I just want to get the value that is already in col1).

My idea was to do something like this:

```
mapping = {"222":"zzz", "444":"fff"}
df = df.select(F.when(F.col('col1').isNull(), mapping[F.col('col2')] ).otherwise(F.col('col1'))
```

I know F.col() is actually a column object and I can't simply do this.
What is the simplest solution to achieve the result I want with pyspark please ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit, when
from itertools import chain

mapping = {"222":"zzz", "444":"fff"}

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])

df = df.select(when(col('col1').isNull(), mapping_expr[col('col2')] ).otherwise(col('col1'))
```